# Late-stage interview: am I being blown off or is this a negotiation tactic?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, united-states

I've gone through four interviews with a high profile company in a big city for a non-entry-level career. The third interview was a 5 hour technical interview where, at the end, the senior staff said I did extremely well, performed "above-average", and wanted to schedule a final interview with me as soon as possible with a C-level executive eight time zones away. They subtly mentioned that they'd love to offer me something but speaking with leadership was a final formality in the process.

The meeting with the executive was scheduled by the next day and for 30 minutes but we hit it off and talked for almost an hour, ending with her saying that she was happy for the opportunity to speak with me and hoped that'd I'd be joining the team.

I got an email within 20 minutes, around 9AM, from the hiring manager saying that he heard nothing but good things and wanted to schedule a quick chat *the same day*. I replied within minutes that I had a few meetings but was available for most of the day and let him know when a good time to call was.

6PM rolls around and I never received a call nor email. This company has been prompt, punctual, and exceedingly courteous up to this point and it seemed like the hiring processes was going extremely well. I can't tell wether this is a sign of disrespect and/or their wanting to sweat me out over the weekend in the hopes that I'll hastily take whatever offer they throw at me next week. I've never been blown off like this before. I have other offers on the table and don't feel rushed and, though I really like this particular company, this behavior makes me nervous.  How should I take it?

Comment: If this isn't "primarily opinion based" then i don't know what is

Comment: It’s impossible to advise you on a specific person’s motivation for behaving some way. If you’d like to rephrase your question to something along the lines of how you can respond to their inaction, you’re likely to get more reliable responses.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't read too much into this.  Maybe something came up that the hiring manager had to deal with that ended up consuming his entire day.  Perhaps he was expecting some information from HR that he needed before the chat.  Perhaps he simply forgot.  I imagine that at least once in your life you've forgotten to reply to an email.

It seems unlikely that anyone would do this as a negotiating tactic.  Most candidates aren't going to feel pressured by getting an offer on a Monday rather than a Friday.

Answer (score 2):

Everything Justin said.

It's [remotely] possible that this is a tactic, that a more promising candidate has appeared, or that the position has been rethought at the last minute, but it sounds far more likely that something else came up. While recruitment will always be important to a hiring manager, there will be a multitude of other things that will be more urgent.

Either way, a productive approach would be to assume good intentions :

> Did I miss a call or e-mail on Friday? I am looking forward to talking
>   further with you about the opportunity with your department.